# IEnumerable<T> assignment

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, variable-assignment

I have two objects declared as `IEnumerable<DateTime>` xVal and `IEnumerable<double>` yVal.
Then some where is my program I have:

```
var xVals = from p in result where p.chemical == "Benzene" select p.SampDate_Name;
var yVals = from p in result where p.chemical == "Benzene" select p.PCL;
```

Then I am trying to the following assignment:

```
 xVal = xVals as IEnumerable<DateTime>;
 yVal = yVals as IEnumerable<double>;
```

And the above code **sets `xVal` and `yVal` to null**.

Could anybody explain what is wrong here? I would very much appreciate the help.

Thanks.

---

One thing is certain: The input is not null. So xVals and yVals are non-null as debugged by me. I am also able to loop through them to get the content of each.
I will try the other suggestions when I get back and post my findings. Thanks a lot folks for your replies.

The problem here was that LINQ is executed lazy, It will be executed when you do either foreach or ToList/ToArray/ToDictionary. The two linq queries in my code were not executed before the assignment was done. Consequently **xVal** and **yVal** were set to null.
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you for (xVals as IEnumerable<DateTime>).ToString(); ?

Comment: When you mouse over the `var` keywords, what does it say?

Comment: Hovering over the var keywords tells this: IEnumerable<DateTime?> and IEnumerable<Double?> respectively. So the debugger is casting to correct type while executing the Linq. So my question is what does it mean by IEnumerable<DateTime?>... this seems to be the issue.

Comment: (xVals as IEnumerable<DateTime>).ToString() throws a run time error saying that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I have no clue why it is so when xVals is set to the result of the Linq query.

Answer (score 3):

The as keyword will set the output to null if the input was null or the cast could not be carried out.

If you used `xVal = (IEnumerable<DateTime>)xVals` you would probably get an exception saying that it could not be cast.

[MSDN description for as keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a generic collection, to get it to IEnumerable, try .AsEnumerable(). So your new code...

```
xVal = xVals.AsEnumerable();
yVal = yVals.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: I tried to do this... but the compiler throws an error saying: cannot implicitly convert type ...IEnumerable<DateTime?> to ...IEnumerable<DateTime>. An explicit conversion exists.

Comment: DateTime? is not the same as DateTime, this is probably why your other cast attempts have returned null, because they are not the same type.

You could try using xVal = xVals as IEnumerable<DateTime?>; and see if you get better results.

Answer (score 0):

The `as` keyword doesn't actually do a cast, but does conversions between related reference types. So if you have a concrete type, you could treat assign it to a new variable with a type of the base class using `as`. If the types are not compatible, then as will return null. This is a good way to do type checking without having to worry about exceptions. Instead you can perform a null check on the result of the conversion.

It's hard to tell what types p.SampDate_Name and p.PCL are, but I would guess strings? If so you can add the cast to the select statement.

```
var xVals = from p in result where p.chemical == "Benzene" select DateTime.Parse(p.SampDate_Name);
var yVals = from p in result where p.chemical == "Benzene" select Double.Parse(p.PCL);
```

Comment: The `as` operator *does* perform a cast (if possible).  And the advantage is not type checking without throwing exceptions (afterall, that's what the `is` operator is for), but rather that you can do the cast and the type check in one operation, which is more efficient.  Furthermore, you don't even need to use the `as` operator when assigning a variable from a concrete type to the base type.